# How to fill by colour a grid cell

Tags: android

i need to fill a whole cell with background colour, but im getting [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thbvM.png)
I used a "match_parent" everywhere and it's gave nothing, please help 
code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gucciBlack"
    android:padding="3dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gucciRed"
        android:text="@string/days" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@color/gucciRed"
        android:text="mon" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@color/gucciLazur"
        android:text="tue" />

 ... other checkboxes (same code) ...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `TextView` width and height are set as `"wrap_content"`. Try changing them to `"match_parent"`, as it follows:

```
   <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_column="0"
         android:layout_row="0"
         android:background="@color/gucciRed"
         android:text="@string/days" />
```

Comment: like i said: i set everything to match_parent and that gave nothing

Comment: Try adding setting the layout_column and layout_row aswell.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean now :/

Comment: Try using the TextView example that i gave you above. There I not only specified the "match_parent" for width and height, but set the "layout_column" and "layout_row" for the first position.

Comment: Set a minSize to your GridLayout ;) The GridLayout itself will have a minimum size, so it will never have with nor height 0.

Answer (score 0):

In `TextView`, Instead of `background` you should be using `textColor`,

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/gucciRed"
    android:text="@string/days" />
```